# spark sql: struct of only non-empty values OR empty struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My spark sql and scala codes:

```
var df = spark.sql(
     s"""
             |SELECT id, a, b, c, d
             |FROM default.table
      """.stripMargin)

var grouped_df = df.withColumn("map", struct("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

the output:

```
{
  "id": 41286786,
  "map": {
    "a": "",
    "b": "",
    "c": "7425",
    "d": ""
  }
 }
```

but I have two requirements:

1, if the value is empty in the `map`, remove it.
So, the above json should look like

```
{
  "id": 41286786,
  "map": {
    "c": "7425"
  }
 }
```

2, if `map` is empty, that is fine.

```
{
  "id": 41286786,
  "map": {
  }
 }
```

how to modify the spark sql and scala codes to meet the above two requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have different schemas in one dataframe. If your schema is :

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- map: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c: string(nullable = true)
 |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
```

then each row must provide a value for each field. You cannot have a field not existing in one row and existing in the other. Is it what you asked for ?

Comment: finally, I need dump the data into HDFS again without empty values.

Comment: You need to set values to null or empty string but you can't remove the field row by row. See dataframe as a table. You can't have a row without all the columns.